# Kibana shows logs in discover with Delay

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana, elasticsearch-5

I have a setup with Elastic Search, Log Stash, Kibana and Filebeat with versions as shown below.

1) Elastic Search: 6.2.4
2) LogStash: 6.2.4
3) kibana: 6.2.4

My Logstash pipeline is as below:

**sudo vim /etc/logstash/conf.d/02-beats-input.conf**

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
        ssl => true
        ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
        ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
    }
}

filter {
  #If log line contains tab character followed by 'at' then we will tag that 
  entry as stacktrace
  if [message] =~ "\tat" {
    grok {
      match => ["message", "^(\tat)"]
      add_tag => ["stacktrace"]
    }
  }

  #Grokking Spring Boot's default log format
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} % 
      {TIME})  %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{NUMBER:pid} --- \[(?<thread>[A-Za-z0- 
      9-]+)\] [A-Za-z0-9.]*\.(?<class>[A-Za-z0-9#_]+)\s*:\s+(? 
      <logmessage>.*)"}
    }

  #grok {
    #  match => { "message" => "(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} 
    # %{TIME})  %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{NUMBER:pid} --- .+? :\s+(? 
    # <logmessage>.*)"}
  #}

  grok {
    match => { "source" => "/var/log/containers/%{DATA:pod_name}_% 
    {DATA:namespace}_%{GREEDYDATA:container_name}-%{DATA:container_id}.log" 
  }
  remove_field => ["source"]
}
```

**sudo vim /etc/logstash/conf.d/30-elasticsearch-output.conf**

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    sniffing => true
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

Elastic search, Kibana, Logstash are running in one VM where as application and Filebeat are running on a different VM.

Currently there is a discrepancy with date between these two VMs, which I need to fix yet.

**The latest log on kibana discover is as below with a specific time stamp.**

```
message:
  {"log":"TACACS+: No port assigned for host, \"XX.XX.XX.XX\". Using default 
  port 49 instead.\n","stream":"stdout","time":"**2018-05- 
  17T00:58:09.401752809Z**"}
  @timestamp:
  May 16th 2018, 17:58:09.408
```

**The latest log at the application as below with a specific time stamp.**

```
{"log":"TACACS+: No port assigned for host, \"XX.XX.XX.XX\".  Using default 
port 49 instead.\n","stream":"stdout","time":"**2018-05- 
17T06:06:44.365607578Z**"}
```

If you see the above two logs, it is clear that kibana is showing up the logs with some delay, particularly in the above case it has delay of around 5 hours. I also see that the delay is keep getting incremented.  I see all the logs on the kibana though. Issue is the delay i am seeing.

Could some one help me understand this behavior ? Is this because the time discrepancy between the two VMs ? both are at PDT time zone. The logs size should be small enough and I dont expect any throttling kicks in.

Please let me know if you need any other details on this.

Comment: did you find any solution to your problem? I'm seeing the same issue with my ELK stack as well

Comment: I have the same problem. The thing is I can get the list of documents by execute the query: ```GET filebeat-2020-04-29/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the mismatch in time/timezone caused the issue. Just sync it and the problem will be solved.